# Delete query to delete data from multiple tables in sql server and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have three tables `mainCategory`, `subCategory` and `products`. I'm showing data in a gridview. I want to delete main category from admin panel but by the time I also need to delete the data from sub category table and products which consist the data as per main category table.

These are the columns in the tables:

1. `mainCategory`

   ```
   mainCatID (primary key)  
   mainCatName
   ```
2. `subCategory`

   ```
   subCatId (primary key) 
   mainCatId
   subCatName 
   mainCatName
   ```
3. `products`

   ```
   productId (primary key) 
   subCatId 
   subCatName  
   productName 
   productImage
   ```

What SQL to write in `SqlCommand` object? Gridview is bound form code behind using function.. kindly help me out

Comment: Can we help you with the SQL statement(s) you've already tried?

Comment: i tried join query but stil its not working it deletes only data from mainCategory table but not remaining two tables.the query is as follows.. DELETE FROM mainCategory FROM mainCategory INNER JOIN subCategory ON mainCategory.mainCatId = subCategory.mainCatId CROSS JOIN products where mainCategory.mainCatId ='" + lbldeleteID.Text + "'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this? It seems easiest just to do it as three separate statements.

```
DELETE FROM Products WHERE SubCatId IN (SELECT SubCatID FROM SubCategory WHERE MainCatId = @mainCatId);
DELETE FROM SubCategory WHERE MainCatId = @mainCatId;
DELETE FROM MainCategory WHERE MainCatId = @mainCatId;
```

Comment: thank you for your support..how to write it in single  string to pass it in SqlCommand obj?

Comment: Keeping the statements separated by semicolons should let you do that the way I wrote it.

Comment: ok is it like following?
string qry="DELETE FROM Products WHERE SubCatId IN (SELECT SubCatID FROM SubCategory WHERE MainCatId = @mainCatId);
DELETE FROM SubCategory WHERE MainCatId = @mainCatId;
DELETE FROM MainCategory WHERE MainCatId = @mainCatId;
";

Comment: Why not just create the code posted here as a stored procedure? Pass through sql like that is painful to deal with.

Comment: Sean has a good point. That's better than passing it all like this. But yes, @user3828556, that looks right. I mean, of course, you should read it and make sure it looks right. Never blindly run code off the internet. But I think that's right.

Comment: procedure is the thing i fear a lot..i just cant write it properly.and also  i need to deal with update query further for the same sir..

Comment: thank u all... the trick worked..the  query in 1st reply  worked..thanks a ton.. i will try for update statement too..if i wont get it i will ask you again..i m knowledge seeker..thank u..

Comment: @user3828556 cool. Please mark this as the accepted answer if it helped you, since that takes it out of the unanswered queue and will make people in the future more able to find help.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities here. One, you have cascade delete enabled on the relationship between these three tables. If that's the case, then it's as simple as the following (assumes no cycles/multiple cascade paths):

```
DELETE
FROM mainCategory WHERE mainCatID = @someId
```

If you don't have cascade delete enable, then it will be a three step process:

```
-- remove the products
DELETE a 
FROM products as a
JOIN subcategory as b 
ON a.subCatId = b.subCatId 
AND b.mainCatID = @someId

-- remove the subcategories
DELETE
FROM subcategory WHERE mainCatID = @someId

-- remove main categories
DELETE
FROM products WHERE mainCatID = @someId
```

Comment: can you tell me how to do cascade delete? is it possible now?

Comment: Assuming you're using SQL Server, go to Management Studio (SSMS), right click the table, select Design, select Table Designer from the menu above, select Relationships, select Insert/Update Specification, change the delete rule to cascade.

Comment: cant change delete rule its disabled ..cant change anything in it