# Update column name in three tables in c#

Tags: c#, sql

i have 3 tables mainCategory, subCategory and products.i want to update main category but by the time it should update the respected data in other remaining tables too.following ar my tables.

```
1. mainCategory 
mainCatId 
mainCatName

    2. subCategory 
subCatId 
mainCatId 
mainCatName 
subCatName

    3. products 
productId 
subCatId 
subCatName 
productName
```

update has to be like,when i change mainCatName it automaticaly changes mainCatId,so it should be change mainCaId and mainCatName,subCatId and subCatName  in other tables too, i have tried a query but its not working
query is:

```
UPDATE    mainCategory
SET       mainCatId =, mainCatName =
FROM      mainCategory 
INNER JOIN
          subCategory ON mainCategory.mainCatId = subCategory.mainCatId 
CROSS JOIN
          products
```

,kindly help me out!

Comment: You forgot the "relational" part of relational database design.

Comment: should i create relation between them in design view? and cascade them?

Comment: Pretty sure [this](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3828556/user3828556) is you or a classmate? If not, your [schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869861/delete-query-to-delete-data-from-multiple-tables-in-sql-server-and-c-sharp) is remarkably similar (read identical) and that is an incredible coincidence.

Comment: it is me only, i tried that query ,the delete query is working properly, m trying update,,its not working for all  related tables,then i made changes in tables added relations,,but then delete is working not update,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link your tables with a Foreign Keys and apply ON UPDATE CASCADE in table definition.

You do not need to have `mainCatName` in subCategory table, because subCategory table should be linked with a foreign key with a mainCategory table.

Same thing with a subCatgoryName in products table.

```
CREATE TABLE mainCategory (
    [mainCatId]   INT        NOT NULL,
    [mainCatName] NCHAR (10) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([mainCatId] ASC));

CREATE TABLE subCategory (
    [subCatId]   INT        NOT NULL,
    [mainCatId]  INT        NULL,
    [subCatName] NCHAR (10) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([subCatId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Table_ToTableMainCat] FOREIGN KEY ([mainCatId]) 
    REFERENCES [mainCategory] ([mainCatId]) ON UPDATE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE products (
    [productId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [subCatId] INT NULL, 
    [productName] NCHAR(10) NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_products_ToTableSubCategory] FOREIGN KEY (subCatId) 
    REFERENCES subCategory(subCatId) ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

You can update mainCatName simply by:

```
 UPDATE mainCategory SET mainCatName='NEW NAME' WHERE mainCatId=SOMEID;
```

Your subCategory table linked with a mainCategory table through a FOREIGN KEY.
Your products table linked with a subCategory table with a FOREIGN KEY.

If you want to get the products of the particular **mainCategory**:

```
SELECT productName, subCatName, mainCatName FROM products
JOIN subCategory ON products.subCatID = subCategory.subCatID
JOIN mainCategory ON subCategory.mainCatID = mainCategory.mainCatID
where mainCategory.mainCatID = 1;
```

If you want to get the products of the particular **subCategory**:

```
SELECT productName, subCatName FROM products
JOIN subCategory ON products.subCatID = subCategory.subCatID
where subCategory.subCatID = 1;
```

If you want to delete the products from a particular subCategory, you just delete the subcategory record and corresponding products will be deleted on cascade.

If you want to change the Name of the subCategory, you just change the record in the subCategory table.

Comment: is mainCatiD a foreign key here? and update cascade in which table? mainCategory table?

Comment: thank you for this query,in subcategory form the user will select main category name and then as per main category user will add sub category and as per sub category user will add products which will be in product table, i have to show maiunCatName column in list of subCategory table to delete subCategory according mainCategory not just by id .

Comment: Add ON DELETE CASCADE to the produst table definition and you can delete all the products from chosen subCategory simply by deleting subCategory record from the subCategory Table.

Comment: and what if i want to delete main category  and its all related data in all other tables?

Comment: The same thing. Add ON DELETE CASCADE to the subCategory table definition. Deletion of the main category will trigger the deletion of the subcategories and deletion of the subcategories will trigger the deletion of the products.

Comment: i done everything as per you suggested, delete cascade is running properly but update cascade is not working properly ,if i update main category name then it changes name in mainCategory table but not in subCategory table.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Only field with a FOREIGN KEY constraint will update on UPDATE CASCADE. You do not need to have mainCategoryName in subCategory table, cause you allready have it mainCategory table. The same with products and subCategory tables: you do not need subCategoryName field in products table, cause you already have it in the subCategory table.

Comment: you mean its  not working because there is mainCatName field in subCategory table..? and so for products table?

Comment: i will definatly remove the mainCatName from subCategory table..but tell me the idea behind..delete cascade is working but not the update cascade..i want understand that.

Comment: the problem occurs not when i  show gridview to display data..but when i click edit link to edit perticular data(main category or sub category or product),edit button pass girdview row data to other page (update page) using query string, it shows error like the field doesnt exist in table.

Comment: This is a problem of the gridview display/edit logic, and not the database.

Comment: yes, i will try to get data from gridview itself and store it in query string and update it as per requirement, before i was passing tables data through query string now i need to pass gridview row to other page..

Comment: ok, i tried as per mention above, the update with cascade is working when updating main category, in sub category update page i have textboxes in which i pass subCatId ,subcatName, a drop down menu which is bound by list of mainCatName from mainCategory table and also has passed mainCatName of perticular row using query String , when i click update ,it gives me following error  "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__subCateg__FB8BF6F035BCFE0A'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.subCategory'.
The statement has been terminated." , i am storing only subCatId,subCatName, and mainCatId.